# What is the time complexity from the function T(n) = T(n//3)) + 1

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

What is the complexity of this function?

`T(n) = T(n/3) + 1`

Is the answer is O(n). But how the step?

Ok, so this is my answer:

`T(n) = T(n/3) + 1`

I use master theorem here,

So it got `T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)`

Compare the n^logb(a) with the f(n)

a = 1, b = 3

```
n^logb(a) = n^log3(1)
          = n^0
          = 1
```

```
f(n) = Θ(n^logb(a))
```

So the solution that I got is `T(n) = Θ(logn)`

This is my answer, but when I searched it, it said the answer `T(n) = Θ(n)` ?

Comment: Have you done any work on your own? *If you have, please mention it in your question.*

Comment: Why do you think the answer is O(n)?

Comment: @AKSingh I've updated my answer, is this correct ?

Comment: @derpirscher Because I'm not sure about my answer, I've updated my answer here, is there any wrong in my answer

Comment: I think `T(n) = Θ(logb (n))` is correct.

Comment: @AKSingh So, `b` here is not a Constant value? it must be included in the solution? I'm sorry for the lot question, Btw, thanks for your editing !

Comment: @AKSingh I read the master theorem rules from [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1168/lecture3.pdf). From this i didn't see any `b` that include in the solution?

Comment: @Yes It is hardly mentioned in any articles. I did learn about it one famous book though. However, you need not worry. Since in algorithms `log n` implies *log n to the base 2* which is an *upper bound* for any `logb (n)`, that is, log n to the base b where be `b > 2`.